# Show there is a point c that satisfy the inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

let $p(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$, be a polynomial of degree $n ≥ 1$. Show that there is a point $c$, $|c| = 1$ where $|p(c)| ≥ 1$.

Any hints on how to proceed

Comment: Wouldn't $p(z) = z/2$ be a counter-example? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @MartinR Or even $z^n/k$ for any positive integers $n,k$. We can make $f$ arbitrarily small on the unit circle this way

Comment: you are right, i edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Assume the contrary and estimate the absolute value of
$$
 1 = \frac{p^{(n)}(0)}{n!}
$$
using [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Comment: Do you mean "1-" instead of "1="?

Comment: @martycohen: I mean it as it is written. For $p(z) = z^n + \ldots$ we have $p^{(n)}(0) = n!$, unless I made some mistake. The Cauchy estimates for derivatives give a contradiction – OP asked for a hint, that's why I did not elaborate further ...

Comment: it will be $1<1$. thank you Martin R.

Answer (score 1):

Define $$f_1(z)=z^n,\quad f_2(z)=f_1(z)-f(z)=-a_{n-1}z^{n-1}-\cdots-a_0$$The sign is chosen because it makes the geometric argument below more intuitive.

Now let's evaluate $f(e^{it})$ for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. $f_1(z)$ just goes around the unit circle $n$ times. That means that if $|f(e^{it})|=|f_1(e^{it})-f_2(e^{it})|<1$ for all $t$, then $f_2(e^{it})$ must "keep up" with $f_1(e^{it})$. Specifically, $f_2(e^{it})$ can never be $0$, and it must also have winding number $n$ around $0$. But this is impossible, since its degree is $n-1$.

Comment: I get what you mean, but why the winding number must be n

Comment: In other words: you apply Rouché's theorem to $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: @MartinR it makes sense now thank you.

Comment: @MartinR Now _I'm_ confused. How would you say Rouché's theorem explains my idea? I never said anything about (the absolute value of) one being bigger than the other, and we're not counting zeroes within a domain, at least not directly.

Comment: @Arthur: If $|f_1(z) - f_2(z)| < 1 = |f_1(z)|$ on the unit circle then Rouché states that $f_1$ and $f_2$ have the same number of zeros inside the unit disk,  which is a contradiction. I think it is at least the same underlying idea.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that makes sense. I was personally thinking more along the lines of $f_2(e^{it})$ lying inside the open circle of radius $1$ around $e^{nit}$, and as $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, that circle goes $n$ times around the origin.

Comment: @Arthur: Rouché is essentially the argument principle (have a look at the "geometric explanation" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouché%27s_theorem), so we probably mean the same thing.

Comment: @MartinR Is been so long since my intro class to complex analysis that I only remember most of the big theorems, and not how to prove them. Or, it turns out, how to apply them more abstractly.

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonality of the exponentials implies

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |p(e^{it})|^2\, dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |e^{int} + a_{n-1}e^{i(n-1)t} + \cdots +a_0|^2\, dt$$ $$ = 1^2+ |a_{n-1}|^2 + \cdots + |a_0|^2 \ge 1.$$

Since $|p(e^{it})|^2$ is continuous and the above is an average, there must exist a $t$ for which $|p(e^{it})|^2\ge 1,$ which implies $|p(e^{it})|\ge 1.$